# How do I avoid this "eventual callback" pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
var foo = function( arg, continuation, behavior ) {
  if ( arg > 1 ) {
    // Do some work with arg, for example send a paged API request.
    console.log("foo: " + arg--);

    continuation( arg, continuation, behavior );
  } else {
    behavior( arg );
  }
},

bar = function( arg, continuation, behavior ) {
  if ( arg > 2 ) {
    // Do some other work with arg.
    console.log("bar: " + arg--);

    bar( arg, continuation, behavior );
  } else {
    continuation( arg, continuation, behavior );
  }
};

bar( 3, foo, console.log );
```

The idea is that I want to specify in the call to `bar` which function will eventually be the callback of `foo`, which is going to be called sometime later in the call graph.

For example, I might not want to `console.log` the final value of `arg`, but use it as the number of times some message is repeated:

```
var baz = function( arg ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arg; i++) {
    console.log("baz");
  }
};

bar( 4, foo, baz );
```

In this case I say that I am *injecting* the `baz` behavior instead of the `console.log` behavior.

In [some code I wrote](https://github.com/jacquerie/github-issues/blob/bbe5e1dc94d79db7e7616d1ff3af9473e5199f10/issues.js) I'm using this pattern to inject the behavior I want. For example, [`cli.js`](https://github.com/jacquerie/github-issues/blob/bbe5e1dc94d79db7e7616d1ff3af9473e5199f10/cli.js) injects the behavior of printing some records to the console, while some other file `db.js` (not yet written) might inject the behavior of adding those records to a Database, and so on.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve what I want. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your functions don't return any values. Hence, I assume that you are only using them for side effects. The `foo` function doesn't use its `continuation` argument at all. The recursion in your functions can be converted into iterative loops. Even better, just set `if (arg > 2) arg = 2` in `bar` and `if (arg > 1) arg = 1` in `foo`. You don't need loops at all. I have no idea what you mean by injecting behavior. Everything said, you need to specify your problem clearly. Perhaps this is an [xy problem](http://ow.ly/LqxUq).

Comment: Mh, perhaps my reduction wasn't clear enough. I'm using `arg--` as a substitute for "do some work with `arg`". For example, think submitting a paged API request with `{ page: arg }`.

Comment: @AaditMShah I edited. Perhaps this makes more sense?

Comment: I think you are looking for `bar(3, function(x) { foo(x, console.log); });`. Do not pass `continuation` to `continuation`, and remove the superfluous `behaviour` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You hint that you will do some asynchronous tasks, so let's mock up an asynchronous task:

```
function mockApiRequest(mockResponse, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(mockResponse) }, 500);
}
```

Now let's modify your code a bit to use our api request:

```
function sendPages(pageNumber, continuation, behavior) {
  if ( pageNumber > 1 ) {
    behavior('Uploading ' + pageNumber);
    mockApiRequest({success:true}, function(apiResponse) {
      if (apiResponse.success) {
        behavior('Successfully uploaded ' + pageNumber);
        continuation(pageNumber-1, continuation, behavior);
      }
      else {
        behavior('Failed to upload ' + pageNumber);
      }
    });
  } else {
    behavior('Unsure what to do with ' + pageNumber);
  }
}
```

As correctly stated by Aadit, it is not a good thing for your function to modify the value passed into it. That is a "side effect" of the function, and will make debugging really hard if you can't expect the value to be the same throughout execution. So you should create a new value for the next continuation call. Rather than modifying `arg` in-place and passing `arg` around, you should consider `arg` to be **immutable**.